# repeat rows in a given sequence format

Tags: oracle

I have a table with following data

```
Order_no | Part_No    | R_from | R_to
    1001 | 1010037-00L|      1 |    5
    1001 | 1010025-00L|      6 |   12
```

I need to get the above data to a report in below manner.

```
R_NO | PART_NO
------------------
   1 | 1010037-00L
   2 | 1010037-00L
   3 | 1010037-00L
   4 | 1010037-00L
   5 | 1010037-00L
   6 | 1010025-00L
   7 | 1010025-00L
   8 | 1010025-00L
   9 | 1010025-00L
  10 | 1010025-00L
  11 | 1010025-00L
  12 | 1010025-00L
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
WITH r_nos ( r_no ) AS (
  SELECT LEVEL
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ( SELECT MAX( R_to ) FROM your_table )
)
SELECT r_no,
       part_no
FROM   r_nos r
       INNER JOIN
       your_table y
       ON ( r.r_no BETWEEN y.r_from AND y.r_to )
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative which doesn't require a separate join. You should test both solutions to see which is more performant for your data etc, though.

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1001 order_no, '1010037-00L' part_no, 1 r_from, 5 r_to FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1001 order_no, '1010025-00L' part_no, 6 r_from, 12 r_to FROM dual)
SELECT r_from + LEVEL -1 r_no,
       order_no,
       part_no
FROM   your_table
CONNECT BY PRIOR order_no = order_no
           AND PRIOR part_no = part_no
           AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
           AND LEVEL <= r_to - r_from + 1
ORDER BY r_no;

      R_NO   ORDER_NO PART_NO
---------- ---------- -----------
         1       1001 1010037-00L
         2       1001 1010037-00L
         3       1001 1010037-00L
         4       1001 1010037-00L
         5       1001 1010037-00L
         6       1001 1010025-00L
         7       1001 1010025-00L
         8       1001 1010025-00L
         9       1001 1010025-00L
        10       1001 1010025-00L
        11       1001 1010025-00L
        12       1001 1010025-00L
```